# C#: WPF MVVM Command Binding vs. Event Callback

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

What would be the point to using MVVM for the close action of File->Exit.

It seems like a lot of work to make a close command when you can simply create an event callback for the Click event.  For something like this that doesn't have anything to do with data or business logic, I don't see the point to using MVVM approach. Why not just use the following:

xaml:

```
<MenuItem Header="_File" Background="WhiteSmoke">
    <MenuItem Name ="Exit" Tag="Exit" Header="Exit" Click="Exit_Click"/>                
</MenuItem>
```

Code behind:

```
private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For *that* case, you have a bit of an argument. If nothing else, *closing* the view could easily be construed as entirely view related, so a `Click` event handler makes sense to start with. View-related code goes in the view, not the VM.

However, I would challenge your notion that a `Command` is that hard to set up. Using a `DelegateCommand`: http://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html requires *two lines* of additional code:

```
public ICommand ExitCommand {get; private set;}

public MyViewModel()
{
    ExitCommand = new DelegateCommand(ExitApp);
}
```

The handler is the same either way. While `Exit` may not need a command, in general, `ICommand` is the right way to go and isn't actually that hard.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right - if handler is pure-UI related then it doesn't break MVVM by any means (despite what some extremists say). MVVM is pattern created to decouple UI and business logic - "UI things" in code are ok.